# vectorizing a matlab / octave FOR loop

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I'm a little confused as to how to vectorize this for loop see code below:

```
array1=[xfreq_orig,yamp_orig,yamp_inv,phase_orig] %frequency, amplitudes, phases to use
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,44100)


aa_sig_rebuilt_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
aa_sig_combined_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
sig_full_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));

for kk=1:1:numel(xfreq_orig);

    aa_sig_rebuilt_L = array1(kk, 2)*cos ((array1(kk,1))*t_rebuilt+(array1(kk, 4))); 
    aa_sig_combined_L = aa_sig_combined_L + aa_sig_rebuilt_L;

end

sig_full_L=(aa_sig_combined_L/max(abs(aa_sig_combined_L))*.8);
```

I came up with this as vectorization

Example:

```
array1=[10,.4,.34,2.32;12,.3,.45,.4];
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,44100)
aa_sig_rebuilt_L = array1(kk, 2).*cos ((array1(kk,1)).*t_rebuilt+(array1(kk, 4)));
aa_sig_combined_L = sum(aa_sig_rebuilt_L);
```

What I don't know how to do is how to get the **kk** variable to access the rows incrementally

THanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use `bsxfun` as follows

```
a = array1;
t = t_rebuilt;

aa_sig_rebuilt_L  = bsxfun(@times, a(:,2) , ...
                     cos( bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@times, a(:,1), t), a(:,4)) ));

aa_sig_combined_L = sum(aa_sig_rebuilt_L);
```

Bear in mind that this will use more memory than the version will a loop (it will use `numel(xfreq_orig)` times as much memory, as it computes every row of `aa_sig_rebuilt_L` before summing them, whereas the loop computes each row, adds it to the sum and then discards it).

The function `bsxfun` is used when you need to perform a binary operation between arrays of different sizes, e.g. a `TxN` matrix and a `Tx1` vector. In this case it would perform the operation between each column of the matrix and the vector.

In your case you have a column vector and a row vector, and the operation is applied to the `i`'th element of the column vector and the `j`'th element of the row vector, to get the `ij`'th element of a matrix.

Comment: In octave, with [broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Broadcasting.html), the third line could read `aa_sig_rebuilt_L = a(:, 2) .* cos(a(:, 1) .* t + a(:, 4))`