# Speeding up for loop since I run out of memory when I vectorise it

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave, vectorization

I was able to get help in vectorising this for loop but if I try and run it when **array1 / xfreq_orig has 500,000 rows or t_rebuilt has 500,000** I run out of ram which I have 16gig of.

```
array1=[xfreq_orig,yamp_orig,yamp_inv,phase_orig] %frequency, amplitudes, phases to use
t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,44100)


aa_sig_rebuilt_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
aa_sig_combined_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
sig_full_L=zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));

for kk=1:1:numel(xfreq_orig);

    aa_sig_rebuilt_L = array1(kk, 2)*cos ((array1(kk,1))*t_rebuilt+(array1(kk, 4))); 
    aa_sig_combined_L = aa_sig_combined_L + aa_sig_rebuilt_L;

end

sig_full_L=(aa_sig_combined_L/max(abs(aa_sig_combined_L))*.8);
```

Here is the vectorised version but I run out of memory when **array1 / xfreq_orig row's are large like 500,000** or if **t_rebuilt** is a large array like **t_rebuilt=linspace(0,2*pi,544100**)

```
a = array1;
t = t_rebuilt;

aa_sig_rebuilt_L  = bsxfun(@times, a(:,2) , ...
                     cos( bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@times, a(:,1), t), a(:,4)) ));

aa_sig_combined_L = sum(aa_sig_rebuilt_L);
```

Here's an explanation of why from Chris Taylor answer. "Bear in mind that this will use more memory than the version will a loop (it will use numel(xfreq_orig) times as much memory, as it computes every row of aa_sig_rebuilt_L before summing them, whereas the loop computes each row, adds it to the sum and then discards it)."

[vectorizing a matlab / octave FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400933/vectorizing-a-matlab-octave-for-loop)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this for loop up since if I vectorise it I will run out of memory?  Is there another way to vectorise it so I won't run out of memory when using large amount of row's for **array1 / xfreq_orig or t_rebuilt**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a case where `bsxfun` (three times!) is probably not a good idea. Sometimes people's paranoia about loops in Matlab goes too far. They're *perfectly fine*, and if used in appropriate situations can be faster than other options in many cases (and have the benefit of being very readable). Update equations and recurrence relations like your system are exactly the type of system that may be better-implemented with a `for` loop. If you time the loop and the `bsxfun` code for smaller inputs you'll see that they are very comparable.

You are doing what looks like a lot of needless allocation in your code. For example, `aa_sig_rebuilt_L` and `sig_full_L` do not need to be preallocated. They will be automatically allocated when they are initialized. You've also built a big array, `array1`, from smaller ones and are performing 2-D indexing on each iteration of the `for` loop. Those will clean up your code and maybe give minor speed-ups, but a you'll actually get the biggest speed-up from getting rid of the temporary variable `aa_sig_rebuilt_L` and putting everything on one line. This ought not to work with JIT compilation, but sometimes it does. Here's my version:

```
t_rebuilt = linspace(0,2*pi,544100);
aa_sig_combined_L1 = zeros(1,length(t_rebuilt));
for i=1:length(xfreq_orig);
    aa_sig_combined_L1 = aa_sig_combined_L1 + ...
        yamp_orig(i)*cos(xfreq_orig(i)*t_rebuilt+phase_orig(i));
end
```

It still takes a while to run on my machine, but you shouldn't run out of memory unless other parts of your code have already used it up (check with `whos`). If you do keep running out of memory, you can try explicitly clearing large unused variables with [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html) ([in Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Status-of-Variables.html#doc_002dclear)). Beyond this you can explore writing you code using [`mex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) or use [`codgen`](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/11/14/generating-c-code-from-your-matlab-algorithms/) to automatically output your function to C code that can be called from Matlab. In Octave: [Dynamically Linked Functions – Oct-Files and Mex-Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Dynamically-Linked-Functions.html#Dynamically-Linked-Functions).

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand, you would like to use Matlab vectorization, meaning, using all the data. On the other hand, you can't do it, because you don't have enough RAM. Even if you do have enough, allocating a lot of RAM will cause your computation to be slower.

One of the solutions is to split your data into parts, load the relevant part from disk, and do a vectorized computation on it. You can play a bit with this parameter to see what yields the best performance.